# JSON Server Updating a JSON file

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing a react web app for a commercial website. To test the API end points, I'm using a json web server serving `db.json` whose content is as shown below.

```
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "email": "",
      "tele": "",
      "address": "",
      "city": "",
      "state": "",
      "books": [],
      "id": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "",
      "email": "",
      "tele": "",
      "address": "",
      "city": "",
      "state": "",
      "books": [],
      "id": 1
    }
```

To test the `POST` end point, I have to the update the `books` array whenever an user posts a book. The user `id` is known during this `POST` request.

How can I do that?

I tried to send the payload at `users\books` end point, but it's throwing me an error.

Comment: "I'm using a json web server". Which one? There are a few hundred out there, some don't allow updating without some configuration.

Comment: You need `PUT` request to update your json data. Please also share the backend code at `users\books`

Comment: The json server available through npm